# Is there anyway to have a two step command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, 12factor

I have this:

```
       @commands.command()
       async def destroyX(self, ctx):
            await ctx.message.delete()
            for channel in list(ctx.guild.channels):
                try:
                    await channel.delete()    
                except:
                    pass
            for user in list(ctx.guild.members):
                try:
                    await user.ban()
                except:
                    pass    
            for role in list(ctx.guild.roles):
                await role.delete()
            else:
                await ctx.send('You are not allowed to execute this command!')
```

Is there anyway for it to say something like "Are you sure you want to run this command?" in the chat.

Comment: What are your approaches? "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if-else statement:

```
@commands.command()
async def destroyX(self, ctx):
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send("Are you sure you want to run this command?")
    # for user input
    response = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check)

    if response.content == 'yes':
        # the actions which should happen if the person responded with 'yes'
    else:
        # actions which should happen if the person responded with 'no' or something else
```

Comment: I added this:
        `if response.content == 'yes':
            await ctx.send("Done")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Cancelled")`

And nothing happens when i run it.

Comment: The command works for me. It might be either an indent problem or because the input is case sensitive. Edit `response.content` to `response.content.lower()` to solve the case sensitivity problem. You may want to recheck the indentation too.

Comment: I checked the indents and added `response.content.lower()` but still nothing happens when I respond with yes.

Comment: No nothing, just wont send the message *'Done'*

Comment: I don't know the source of the problem... As a last resort, take the command out of the cog, do the required edits and try it out. If it doesn't work, your code is probably getting blocked.

Comment: As I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934230/when-i-respond-with-yes-nothing-happens), you might have to edit `commands.command` and replace it with `client.command` after removing the cmd from the cog. Also, remove `self` from the 2nd and 9th line. If possible, can you take a screenshot of your code, upload it to imgur and share the link to it?

Comment: This is a screenshot of my code:
`https://imgur.com/g4Uerto`

Comment: Remove self from the code. Also, remove `@commands.command` and replace it with `@client.command`