# When I respond with 'yes' nothing happens?

Tags: discord, discord.py, warnings

This is my code so far:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def destroy(self, ctx):
        def check(m):
            em = discord.Embed()
            return em.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channl

        await ctx.message.delete()
        em = discord.Embed(color=15859772, title = ":rotating_light: WARNING WARNING :rotating_light:", description=f"{ctx.author.mention} Are you sure you want to run this command? yes/no")
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
        # for user input
        response = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    
        if response.content.lower() == 'yes':
            await ctx.send("Done")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Canceled")
```

Not sure what has gone wrong. But if I respond with *yes* nothing gets sent and I get no errors?

Comment: What is `ctx.channl`?

Answer (score 2):

Your `check` makes no sense to me. Why do you put an embed in there?

**Try this one instead:**

```py
        def check(m):
            return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel
```

This will check if the author of the command is responding in the correct channel.

***As mentioned in the comments the following code works fine for me:***

```py
@client.command() # As you use client.wait_for
async def destroy(ctx):
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel

    await ctx.message.delete()
    em = discord.Embed(color=15859772, title=":rotating_light: WARNING WARNING :rotating_light:",
                        description=f"{ctx.author.mention} Are you sure you want to run this command? yes/no")
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
    # for user input
    response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    if response.content.lower() == 'yes':
        await ctx.send("Done")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Canceled")
```

*If you still have errors I assume you are using `commands.command` in the wrong way/defined things wrong.*

Comment: I've tried that already but still the same issue.

Comment: There is no `self.client.wait_for`. Just try `client.wait_for`.

Comment: Still the same thing

Comment: Works fine for me, I use `client.command`, so I guess you defined things wrong.

Comment: I changed it to `client.command()` but still wont work

Comment: As in it still wont say *'Done'* when I respond with *'yes'*